# Empty object returned but can't execute the !posts if statement to throw an error using mongoose in express app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In a REST Api POSTS App i am testing the original callback method with async/await in express app connected via mongoose to mongo db but i recieve an empty object since the database collection is empty in order to test for a throw error. In theory using the `next` callback as per express documentation should shoot to my error handling middleware saved in server.js file but it doesn't instead it executes with status 200 and empty object `[]` returned to the client.

When the database posts collection is populated it will infact return all the documents but i want it to fire the error handler when there arn't any.

Does anyone know of a solution to this issue or recognise what i maybe during wrong ?

Heres my schema

```
//posts.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const {Schema} = mongoose;

const postsSchema = new Schema({


    title: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now()
    }

});

const PostModel = mongoose.model('PostModel', postsSchema, 'posts');

module.exports = PostModel;
```

My server.js file

```
//500 error handling middleware 

app.use( ( err, req, res, next) => {
        res.status(500);
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/500.html'));
        console.error(err.stack);
});
```

Now my controller file

````
//posts_controller.js

const Post = require('../models/posts');

router.get('/posts/:all', async(req, res, next) => {
    
    if(!req.params.all) {
    
        return res.status(400).send('Missing URL parameter all');
    
    }

    await Post.find({}, function(err, posts){


        if(err) {

            return next(new Error('Error Thrown'));

        }

        if(!posts) {

            return next(new Error('No posts found'));

        } else {


            res.status(200).send(posts);


        }

        return posts;

    });
});

What is interesting is that promises don't work either still get empty object Any Help much appreciated!

```//posts_controller.js promised based

router.get('/posts/:all', (req, res, next) => {

    if(!req.params.all) {

        res.status(400).send('Missing URL parameter for all');

   }

   Post.find({})
    .then((doc) => {

        if(!doc) {

           throw new Error('No ducuments found to return');

         }

         return doc;

     })
     .then((doc) => {

         res.status(200).send(doc);
        console.info(doc);


    .catch((next));
   
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `Post.find()` returns an empty array in the instance where no documents are found, and an empty array is a truthy value, thus `!posts` is false.

You should check for the length or the array instead.

```
if(!posts.length)
```

Comment: Thanks for checking in, i tried that with this if(!posts.length === 0) but that still does not fire the code within the if statement. Any other ideas welcome.

Comment: You should do either if(!posts.length) or if(posts.length === 0), but not combine both the way you did.

Comment: This is working correctly, most of the blogs and articles online suggest if(!posts) method , i wondering why when it doesnt seem to work, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Sure. I can only speculate that maybe the articles you have read make use of a different query method - or api alltogether - that actually returns either `null` or `undefined` in case no document is found - in which case  `if(!posts)` is actually correct.